# Pandas number formatting, negative numbers with parentheses

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want take the following dataframe(df):

```
Team    Group1    Group2    Group3
green    1         5         -6
blue     -3        10        5
red      -7        9         -8
```

and apply this formatting for only the Group1:Group3 columns:

```
DF = '{0:,.0f}'.format(x) if x > 0 else '({0:,.0f})'.format(abs(x)) for x in DF
```

or using a def which i can't seem to be able to get the syntax correct for:

```
def formatting(x):
 if i > 0:
     '{0:,.0f}'.format(x)
 else:
     '({0:,.0f})'.format(abs(x))

DF.applymap(formatting)
```

the intended output would like this:

```
Team    Group1    Group2    Group3
green    1         5         (6)
blue     (3)       10        5
red      (7)       9         (8)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.6+, you can use formatted string literals, also known as f-strings:

```
def formatter(x):
    return str(x) if x >= 0 else f'({abs(x)})'

for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(formatter)

print(df)

    Team Group1  Group2 Group3
0  green      1       5    (6)
1   blue    (3)      10      5
2    red    (7)       9    (8)
```

Comment: thank you for your help!  is there anyway for this to iterate through all columns?  and then would this function ignore actual strings?

Comment: You could just iterate `df.columns[1:]`, i.e. ignoring first column, as in my answer. For numeric types you can use `df.select_dtypes`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is perfect!